# async keyword/Promise equivalence

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, settimeout

How are these 2 not equivalent?

This doesn't work.

```
const message = async () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("delayed")
        return true
    }, 1000)
}
```

but this does?

```
const message = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("delayed")
            resolve(true)
        }, 1000)
    })
}
```

Does this mean you can only "return" in an async function if it is directly in the scope of the function(not in another function)?

Is the promise returned by an async function different than a regular promise? How is it initialized exactly?

Comment: A `return` inside a `setTimeout` callback is meaningless: it doesn’t return anywhere; it’s like a `return` inside a `forEach`. This is less about asynchronicity, but more about semantics.

Comment: To make it simple, whatever you return from inside the async function, will be what's wrapped into a promise. Since you don't return anything from inside the async function, no value is resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `message` function in your first example has no `return` statement to pass a value for its resolution.

The Promise in your second example passes a value to `resolve()` explicitly.

> Does this mean you can only "return" in an async function if it is directly in the scope of the function(not in another function)?

Yes. The return value of a function is determined by a `return` statement in that function. Putting a `return` statement in some other function will set the return value for *that* function.